# Little and Big Endian Values

Tags: assembly, endianness

I am currently taking Computer Systems and have no clue as to what is going on. I have a question as such in my homework:

In a byte addressable system byte sequences are following from address `0x10010000 0x23, 0x1a, 0x25, 0xaf, 0xef, 0xa5, 0x5a, 0x61, 0x6f, 0x73`. If the system uses 48-bit register and supports a load load command '`ld48bit <rt>, <address>`' to load 48-bit information from memory. What would be the content of register `t0` after '`ld48bit $t0, 0x10010002`' in following scenarios?

1. System uses big endian convention.
2. System uses little endian convention.

Does that mean we load the value of `0x10010002` into `$t0`, but we change it to 48-bits instead of 8-bits? Then we list the value of `t0` in descending order when using big endian, and ascending order when using little endian? I am honestly not sure on how to approach this problem first. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have an array of 10 bytes - 80 bits. The processor can load 6 bytes - 48 bits. But it is being asked to read from (address + 2). That means the first 2 bytes and the last 2 bytes you listed will be ignored.

In the case of big-endian memory storage, the first byte encountered is the most significant, so the data register will 'appear' to hold the bytes in the same order as you present.

```
0x25afefa55a61
```

In the case of little-endian memory storage, the first byte encountered is the least significant, so the byte order read into the register will be reversed.

```
0x615aa5efaf25
```

Humans usually use big-endian descriptive format, for example in `1000` the most significant digit is first.

Comment: thank you! I do not understand why exactly we have to ignore the first 2 digits too, though.

Comment: @Riadiani because the question says *"byte sequences are following from address `0x10010000`"*, but goes on to give the instruction `ld48bit $t0, 0x10010002` which is 2 bytes greater than the array base address.